# connecting sql server to oracle database

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g

I have been asked to check whether we can install SQL Server(08/12) on one system that can be connected to existing oracle database(11), just for simple testing purposes.

What are the steps to do that, can anybody provide me useful links ?

Thank you.

Comment: just a simple noob question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you setup a linked server to an Oracle database on SQL 2000/2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307636/how-do-you-setup-a-linked-server-to-an-oracle-database-on-sql-2000-2005)