# Running TSQL on Oracle Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

I'm supposed to migrate script and data for an Oracle data warehouse to SQL server. They want to transfer data last, so first I'm converting the existing PLSQL code into TSQL. Is there any way for me to test if the converted TSQL is returning the correct rows on the existing Oracle database?

Comment: Not without data. It doesn't even make sense to test if the queries return the same thing when the data isn't there. How would you know?

Comment: The data is in an Oracle database, but will be migrated once I confirm that the queries are converted to T-SQL. So I need to be certain that they work..

Comment: The point is that if your intention is to permanently move this data there is no way you can test the queries without data. This is why this kind of thing should be done first on a test server so you can test this stuff.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to query the data _on_ the Oracle server, but with a TSQL procedure. I'm considering the remote link option but maybe there's something else.

Comment: If it was my project there is no way I would consider that to be adequate testing. One of the most important aspects, after data accuracy is performance. You simply can't test the performance when the data lives in Oracle. The only way to test it is to run the query the exact same way it will be run after the migration.

Comment: I know but I want to confirm data accuracy first as I'm not familiar with the TSQL syntax. I will have to run performance tests as well..

Comment: Right. The only to test the accuracy is to run the queries right? You can't compare results against Oracle if you don't have the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* set up a remote link to Oracle from SQL Server.  This can be a bit more complicated than you would want.  After all, the database hierarchy and naming conventions are different (for instance, SQL Server uses 3-part naming for tables in a database, Oracle uses 2-part naming for tables in a schema).

But, if you just want access to a single table, then this *might* be reasonable.  The basic command to use is `sp_addlinkedserver`.  But there are details.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307636/how-do-you-setup-a-linked-server-to-an-oracle-database-on-sql-2000-2005) is a question with a detailed answer.

As for the porting project, I would suggest that you create sample data on both Oracle and SQL Server and use it to validate the port.  Of course, you will have to eventually test on the real data.  But being able to build the system using sample data that is safe from production users should facilitate your work.