# How to connect remotely to server using sql studio

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL but this is what i would like to do. 
I have these information
hostname: hostname.com
port: 1523
SID: oracledb
Username: username
Password: password

I would like to connect remotely to this server to retrieve data using MSSQL studio. [image] Can you please explain to me how to do it. thank you

Comment: `sid` says `oracleDB`. I think my friend that you are trying to use SSMS 2014 to connect to an `Oracle Database`

Comment: If this is an Oracle DB but you must use SSMS, I think you need to connect to your SQL Server and then create a linked server to your Oracle server.

Comment: Yes i am trying to connect to an oracle database using SSMS. how can i do it ?

Comment: Here is a helpful link to a post about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307636/how-do-you-setup-a-linked-server-to-an-oracle-database-on-sql-2000-2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly connect to and query an Oracle database using SQL Server Management Studio. You can, however, create a SQL Server [linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) to your Oracle instance and query remotely through that. You would connect to your SQL Server using SSMS like normal, but query your linked server using the linked server name in 4-part naming fashion, e.g: `select * from [MyOracleServer]..MyDatabase.MyTable`.

Here is a SQLMag tutorial on doing this: [Connecting SQL Server and Oracle Using Linked Servers](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/connecting-sql-server-and-oracle-using-linked-servers).

Answer (score 0):

read this thread from MSDN 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6d61861-b271-4d93-b14e-12ba9356798f/connect-to-oracle-via-sql-server-management-studio?forum=sqltools

> Question Sign in to vote 3 Sign in to vote Yes, you add linked server
>   and access Oracle data from SSMS and here is how you to add it. These
>   links will help you understand how to add and trouble shoot the
>   issues.  Setting Up an Oracle Linked Server
>
> How to set up and troubleshoot a linked server to an Oracle database
>   in SQL Server
>
> Also in order to migrate an Oracle database to SQL Server, we can use
>   SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle)
>
> There is a migration assistant available for Oracle to SQL Server
>   Migration
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3e8722ae-77f3-4288-906d-f421e24d322f&displaylang=en
>
> But all the system objects becomes null in this scenario
>
> Thanks Sreekar
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx